# how to create notification service for incoming text?

Tags: android, service, notifications

I am newbie to android ..And I am totally confused by reading all SOQs to solve the issue of creating notification service for incoming text alerts. Can u please help me out with this by explaining the steps how to create background service with a specific time for example 5 minutes and that service is for notifying the user incoming text.
Thanks much.

```
  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
  import android.widget.Toast;

    public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] messages = null;
    String strMessage = "";

    if (myBundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
        messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            strMessage += "SMS From: "
                    + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            strMessage += " : ";
            strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
            strMessage += "\n";
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
 }
```

and in the manifest file I wrote,

```
 <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I used BrodcasRreciever class to get the sms alerts is that a correct way?

Comment: then show your code we dont need to work from the scratch. show what you had done in your quetion so reader can know what is wrong and where you stuck.

Comment: I have added the permission and <receiver> related code in the manifest file but still not able to see the output after getting the incoming message....what should I do?

Comment: Edit your question and add your code to it.

Comment: have you got it working ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NotificationManager for creating notifications. instead of that Toast inside your `Receiver`, use `Notification`. See a sample code is below.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager1= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent i=new Intent(context,TragetActivity.class);// TargetActivity is opened when you click on the notification.
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);

// Build notification
// Actions are just fake
Notification noti2=new Notification(R.drawable.icon2, "New SMS from " + "Nizam", System.currentTimeMillis());
noti2.setLatestEventInfo(context, "SMS", "Hii", pi);
noti2.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
//Show notification
notificationManager1.notify(1, noti2);
```